# Gzip compression not working after update WordPress 4.9.6

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, gzip, pagespeed

After updating my sites to latest version of WordPress 4.9.6 all my sites are showing gzip compression F(0) on page speed tools (gtmetrix, google). I have tried all possible ways (.htaccess, gzip compression plugin) to resolve it but didn't get success.
Before updating to the latest version of WordPress my all sites speeds were above 80% on all speed test tools and now all are showing 30 to 35% score. Kindly help me to get out of this problem.  thanks

Comment: Problem is with single site or all sites ?

Comment: are you sure its not a server issue?

Comment: Yes, Server side is OK. @Owi

Comment: Problem with all sites, @AbdulManan

Comment: Well again - WP doesn't have much in common with GZIP compression as its a server side task (you can achieve that with code but its non-trivial).
Could you provide a link to an example website?

Comment: here is example website. devspot(dot)pk

Comment: another one is, myairauthority(dot)com

Comment: Fixed from server side, Thanks @Owi

Comment: That's great to hear